# Login Loop for Guest Account only on 16.04

Tags: login, 16.04, lightdm, login-screen

I have some 40 Dell Latitude E6410s I maintain in my classroom for student use.  I have successfully setup and used special 'guest' accounts so the directories are wiped between uses.  This scheme worked well for 14.04 LTS.  I just tried a trial setup of 16.04 LTS (which in other test environments solves an unrelated annoying problem with some software we would like to run).

The problem is that after the upgrade I can no longer log into the "guest" account.  All the administrator and standard user accounts work fine but the automatic "guest" login goes into a loop ([as described in other questions, *login the screen clears and the system starts to setup but fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) in [some way I can't determine and returns to the login screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759995/after-upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04-login-screen-runs-in-a-loop-while-console-logi)).

What makes this different is that the 'guest' directory is created on the fly so .Xauthority and local log files aren't visible to me.  I can't get much information or apply some of the proposed fixes outlined in the referenced sites for more permanent accounts.

I have changed the 50-unity-greeter.conf file to allow guest logins removing any files that might prevent guest logins.

1. Where can I get more diagnostics on what seems to be going wrong here?
2. What has changed in the handling of guest accounts?  (*Yes I have a custom skel directory which is managed by a 'special account' to setup the default environment for the students*)

---

**UPDATE:** I found the cause of the loop but not answers to the posited questions.  The source of the problem in my case which posits another more general one is in [the execution on the auto.sh and prefs.sh scripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) in the /etc/guest-session directory.  These scripts are intended to run ahead of the login so as to do last minute configurations.  I have one of each that ran fine under 14.04.  The offending instruction is a usermod command:

```
usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

which I use to allow guests to use devices plugged into the USB port.  This command worked well in the auto.sh stage of the script under 14.04.

Under 16.04 if I place this command in prefs.sh (where it seems like it should belong) I get the infinite loop problem.  If I place it in auto.sh the script executes normally but it is ineffectual (probably because it needs root privilages to change groups.

I found this by trial and error. I still don't know where the login sequence is being logged.  I tried checking /var/log/lightdm/ logs and the revealed other minor issues but nothing about the failure mode of these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

While it may not be perfectly complete answer to this general query, a response to another more specific question I posted covers what I needed to know about the differences between the handling of guest accounts in 14.04 to 16.04 [ https://askubuntu.com/a/771284/534729 ]