# startup problem after download update

Tags: 16.04, lts

I have Ububtu 16.04 and recently downloaded an update and ever since I cannot access Ubuntu. at startup screen I am now asks for a password which i never had to use at startup before, when I enter my password that I had setup to verify downloads etc it wont accept it . after I enter my password the screen goes blank and then returns to previous screen asking for password

Comment: Please consider going to ubuntuforums.org

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://askubuntu.com/questions/759871/cant-login-to-ubuntu-16-04-after-upgrade and http://askubuntu.com/questions/759995/after-upgrade-from-14-04-to-16-04-login-screen-runs-in-a-loop-while-console-logi

Comment: @userDepth there's no reason that this user needs to take his question elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

- replace your_username, shown below, with your username

  1. boot the computer and observe the GRUB menu
  2. choose `advanced options`
  3. choose `root access`
  4. type `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`
  5. type `cd /home/your_username`
  6. type `sudo chown your_username:your_username .ICEauthority`
  7. type `sudo chown your_username:your_username .Xauthority`
  8. type `reboot`
  9. login like normal